# Making search bar notify the viewController that user is about to search

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I am implementing a search feature in my app. The app consists of a view controller and a custom class that handles the search logic. This custom class is called `SearchController`.

My goal is to make the searchBar notify the view controller when the user is about to begin searching (exactly the same behaviour as the `UISearchBarDelegate` method `searchBarShouldBeginEditing`).

Normally, you would just declare `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` inside `SearchController` but I am trying to call this method from inside the `viewController` because I want something in my view to change when this event happens (and thus the viewController should be handling it, not the searchController).

`SearchController` class:

```
class SearchController: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    var searchButton = UIBarButtonItem? = nil

    /* Other irrelevant class properties */

    func setup() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
        /* other setup */
    }
}
```

`ViewController` class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let searchController = SearchController()  

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.setup()
    }

    /* setup a tableview to display results... this part of the implementation works fine */
}
```

I omitted the majority of these two classes because the search feature already works. The only thing I am struggling with is finding a way to let `viewController` know when the user is about to begin typing into the search field.

I tried making `viewController` implement `UISearchBarDelegate` but I am already making `SearchController` implement `UISearchBarDelegate` so why can't I access the delegate methods inside `viewController`?

I hope I made myself clear, I can clarify this post further if necessary. I have been tearing my hair out trying to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Why not use `UISearchController`? No need to reinvent this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, a `searchBar` cannot have 2 delegates, so you're gonna have to find a way to work around that.

One way to go about this is this:

```
protocol SearchControllerDelegate: class{
    func searchBarDidBeginEditing()
}

class SearchController: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

    weak var delegate: SearchControllerDelegate?

    private let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    func setup() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        delegate?.searchBarDidBeginEditing()
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, SearchControllerDelegate{

    var searchController = SearchController()
    func setUP(){
        self.searchController.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarDidBeginEditing() {
        /// perform some action here
    }

}
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UISearchController` as rmaddy suggested, implement `UISearchResultsUpdating`

*ViewController* class:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil) 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.delegate = self

        ....
    }

    // Called when the search bar's text or scope has changed or when the search bar becomes first responder.
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

Or if you really want to implement the search bar logic yourself, you can go with the closure:

*SearchController* class:

```
class SearchController: NSObject, UISearchBarDelegate {

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()
    var searchButton = UIBarButtonItem? = nil
    var didBeginSearching: (() -> ())?

    /* Other irrelevant class properties */

    func setup() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
        /* other setup */
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        didBeginSearching?()
    }
}
```

*ViewController* class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let searchController = SearchController() 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.setup()
        searchController.didBeginSearching = { [weak self] in
            //Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think what I was looking for was actually someone else's answer. However, I will take a closer look at this in the morning and see if I should mark this as the accepted answer.